# how to use ObjectListView in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, objectlistview

I am using a wxpython to contain an ObjectListView. I tried to put it into a wx.panel, but failed. The following is the image[image]

I am very puzzled that why the ObjectListView is only showed in a 16x16 square? My code to realize the ObjectListView:

```
and my code to use it:    
`LeftList = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )    
self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,          wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )    
p1 = MyListCtrl(self.m_panel2, -1)    
LeftList.Add( p1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )    
bSizer12.Add( LeftList, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )`

and my code of MyListCtrl is:    
`class MyListCtrl(wx.Panel):    
def __init__(self, parent, id):       
wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
self.olv = ObjectListView(self, id, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.NO_BORDER)    
self.Layout()    
self.olv.SetColumns(...)  `
```

Then the result is the image I posted at the head

My problem is what should I use to contain the ObjectListView in wxpython and how to use it

Comment: It is easier if you copy and paste your code, instead of posting screen shots. Just make sure all your code is indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: Have you considered placing your `ObjectListView` in a sizer and setting the `wx.Expand` flag? Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/)?

Comment: @acattle Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have tried the tutorial and it worked. But I want to create a class containing the ObjectListView and add it into wx.BoxSizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As acattle has already pointed out, you can follow my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/) on the subject. I don't see anything in your screenshots that shows you actually adding any data to the ObjectListView widget or setting its size. If you resize the frame slightly and the widget magically appears, then you need to add a call to Layout(), probably at the top sizer or frame level. Otherwise, we'll need some real code to figure this out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wrote a program using wxpython and imported ObjectListView in the splitter window. But right now, I want to change its structure and use it directly without changing the code too much. My previous code:

Comment: I have edited my problem and changed the code in my question. Right now, I changed the MyListCtrl into a function and return the ObjectListView and then add it into the BoxSizer. It really works, but I still want to use the previous way of making an instance of class